# How to get the full filenames in the error messages?

Tags: errors, luatex

I'm getting the following error message from lualatex:

```
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload.sty...ive/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-init.lua:176: attempt to index global 'luatexbase' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
        ...ive/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-init.lua:176: in function 'early'
        ...ive/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-main.lua:283: in function 'main'
        [\directlua]:1: in main chunk.
```

The error message is legitimate in my use case, `luatexbase` is really `nil`.

How do I get the full filename in the Lua error message, i.e. `/usr/share/texlive/` instead of `...ive/` ?

I know that I can look up filenames (e.g. `kpsewhich luaotfload-init.lua`) afterwards, but in this question I'm interested in including full absolute filnames in error messages.

FYI I'm already using `max_print_line=1000 error_line=254 half_error_line=238 lualatex` to prevent line breaks within Tex messages.

Comment: Won't help for the log file, but if you want to look up the full path afterwards, you can use `kpsewhich luaotfload-main.lua`

Comment: How did you manage to get a nil luatexbase table? The table is setup by the kernel. Or don't you have a current latex?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I'm running this with `lualatex --ini`, and `luatexbase` is `nil` there. Please note that in this question I'm not interested in fixing this error.

Comment: Well the error messages are from lua, so setting tex options won't help, you probably would have to install some other (lua) error handler.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Could you please advise how?

Comment: Sorry no idea, I never needed it. And I'm not really a lua programmer, I know only basic stuff about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't look like that is possible even if you use `pcall` to trap the error and get the message as a Lua string, it has already been truncated, it isn't tuncated by the print routines.

this would apparently require a change in the C code of Lua itself, see for example

http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2011-12/msg00038.html

Comment: Just copying the relevant info from the link in case the link disappears: To make it happen, `ar.short_src ` should be changed to `ar.source` in the C source code of Lua.